# Product-σAlgebra of Lebesgue sets on $R$ is subset of the Lebesgue sets on $R^2$

Tags: products

I want to show that
$\Gamma(R)\times\Gamma(R)$ is a subset of $\Gamma(R^2)$, where $\Gamma(\cdot)$ are the lebesgue sets of $R$ or $R^2$ respectively.
What can i do for that and why is it a subset and not equal as one would probably estimate?

To show $\Gamma$(R)^2 is  subset of $\Gamma$($R^2$)

Comment: Have a look [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to write with MathJax

Answer (score 0):

$\Gamma(\mathbb{R}) \times \Gamma(\mathbb{R}) \subset \Gamma(\mathbb{R}^2)$, this is by the construction of the Lebesgue measure for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

To show it is a proper subset, just observe the set $\{1\} \times A$ where $A\not\in \Gamma(\mathbb{R})$ has zero Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$, thus 
$\{1\} \times A \in \Gamma(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and clearly  $\{1\} \times A \not\in \Gamma(\mathbb{R}) \times \Gamma(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Good point so far. It can be also equal, but it's not equal in all cases, right?

Comment: What do you mean by "it can be also equal" ?

Comment: sorry, i mean it doesnt't have to be a so called proper subset, but a subset (which is weaker)